# Git vs SVN: Performance and Storage

Tags: git, svn, version-control, backup

I want to use one of Git or SVN (Subversion) as a **backup system**. The only important thing for me is the Storage and Performance of the system. I searched around and most of the results I found were comparing them for features related to source control such as branching, local repositories, etc. However, as I mentioned, I am **NOT** looking for such features.

In short, I want to know:

- Which one is more efficient for storage (takes less space)
- Which one is more reliable (if there is a crash when pushing/committing, which one handles errors better)
- Which one does things faster
- Which one can handle **large-scale** repositories better (if too many revisions submitted, which would perform better)
- ...

I would appreciate if there were some facts (experiments) added to the comparisons. I'm looking for solid evidence.

Comment: A backup system of what? Configuration files? Binary data? In any event, security-wise, git wins hands down (since all commits are uniquely hashed).

Comment: If all you want is to back up things, back-up software might work better than source control software.

Comment: @fge files are textual. HTML files/source files/JavaScript/CSS, etc.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen No, I'm still looking for a version control and especially looking for delta-based repositories.

Comment: @robmayoff There are too many variables that could take too much time testing. I thought maybe someone had done such comparison before and put effort into it. Also, it needs great understanding of both systems. I'm slightly familiar with both but not that much.

Comment: One advantage of svn is that partial checkouts are easy. That is the only thing I can think of that svn has over git. I think I read of some game developers somewhere that checked in GB-large binary files where they preferred svn over git, but I can't remember where. For a real backup system I would suggest looking a bacula.

Comment: I **do** need the partial commit features (`svn -update` command) but if the performance difference is big enough, it can be overlooked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go for `git`, there is just no competition:

- it is much more secure (all commits are uniquely hashed),
- it is much more compact (the *entire* Linux kernel history from the last 5 years takes less than 1 GB on my machine),
- it is so much faster it is not even funny,
- it is easily replicated since it is decentralized.

Of course, using git is vastly differently to SVN. But tutorials also are aplenty.

[Here](http://bokov.net/weblog/project-managment/comparing-svn-vs-git-in-performance-test/) is a link comparing git and svn performance in a few selected scenarios.

Comment: Excellent point by @DonBranson. Also, could you please offer some statistics or some other sort of data to back your points? Especially the *so much faster* part. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @DonBranson: simple, you are guaranteed that what you put in is what you get out. The entire file tree is hashed, and the hash of a commit depends on the commit metadata (date, author, message, etc) _and_ parent commits as well. And of course, a commit hash also depends on the hash of the file tree which is associated.

Comment: @fge - That has nothing to do with security.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: a simple Google search can tell you that. But here is one URL: http://bokov.net/weblog/project-managment/comparing-svn-vs-git-in-performance-test/

Comment: @DonBranson really? So, you mean you get someone cracking into your VCS server and change a file, introducing a backdoor, someone retrieves it, and this has nothing to do with security?

Comment: @fge.  Yeah, sorry.  If they can do that, they can change the hash, too.  Security is about authentication and authorization, and the hash doesn't do either of those for you.  It might help you detect that your auth system was breached, but nothing more.

Comment: @DonBranson wrong, wrong, wrong. If you try and retrieve the tree from your VCS server in your local repository, the tampering will have been detected. You seem to forget about the integrity part of security (also, have you even considered disk corruption?). Oh, and as to authorization and authentication, git has gitolite, which is more fine-grained than what SVN can even do.

Comment: @fge - You're missing the point that if they have access to corrupt a tracked file, they have the access they need to corrupt the file that holds the hash, and you'd never know the repo was corrupted.

Comment: @DonBranson wrong again! If the hash of _one_ blob changes, the hash of the _file tree_ has to change, therefore the hash of the _commit_ has to change, therefore the hashes of the _entire commit tree from that commit onwards_ also change. Which means the next time you try and pull from that repo, corruption will be evident. Read more about how git stores its data and you will understand.

Comment: -1 Hashing is _not_ a security feature. In git it is used for consistency, but a similar functionality has SVN too.

Comment: @KingCrunch so, integrity is not security? I'll never host my code on your servers...

Comment: @fge - I'm wrong based on your assumption, and you're wrong based on my assumption. ;)

You're assuming that other commits were pushed before the corruption was detected, and I'm assuming there were none.

Comment: @DonBranson if you try and put a commit on a corrupted remote, it will _fail_, since the hash of the _parent commit_ will be different on the corrupted remote.

Comment: @fge No. At least not on it's own. "Security" has many aspects, but saying "it is (more) secure, because it uses hashses" is _dangerous_ in my eyes. And of course I will never host code on your servers, when _this_ is your idea of security ;) And btw: Changing hashes can also occur in a "normal" situation, for example when you rebase a branch. Yeah, I know, I should not push a rebased branch, unless I know, what I am doing, but sometimes I know

Comment: @KingCrunch and I say, as far as a VCS is concerned, it is an essential feature. I want to be guaranteed that if I put something in, I'll get the exact same "something" out. SVN makes _no_ guarantee.

Comment: @fge - Ah, okay, I see what you're saying - that since my local repo has a hash different than the remote repo, I can't push any more.  Point taken.  Also, now that the corruption has been detected, we can blast the corrupted repo and restore it from someone's clone.

Comment: @fge &KingCrunch, given that it may allow us to detect a breach of security, it's related to security in the same sense that /var/log/messsages is.

Comment: @fge The link you sent me was EXACTLY what I wanted in case of speed. Please put it in your answer. I got what I wanted. Thanks for **ALL** the answers and comments from everyone. I really appreciate it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Data_Integrity: " Linus Torvalds has said, 'Git uses SHA-1 in a way which has nothing at all to do with security.... It's just the best hash you can get.... It's about the ability to trust your data.'"

Comment: 1. It is not much more secure. 2. It is not much more compact. 3. The git wiki page you refer to has many mistakes according to http://svnvsgit.com/.

Answer (score 5):

#### Use [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/) for backup.

If it's critical that you keep the history of the files you are backing up, use [`rdiff-backup`](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/)

Git and SVN are not backup utilities.

---

I understand you don't care about the features of the SCM tools, **which should be an indicator that you don't need one**, but nevertheless(!), if you use a SCM tool like Git or SVN, you're going to have to deal with actual commits.

I would consider this to be a huge pain in the ass if my only goal is to have an entire copy of a collection of files.

---

In terms of **speed**, if you have a fast connection to your backup destination, `rsync` and `rdiff-backup` are going to be fastest. Git will spend time processing files (compressing them, building objects, etc).

If you have a slower connection, Git might be better because you'll be transferring a compressed version of the files. You'll just have the processing time up front

---

If **security** is a concern, know that you can use something like `ssh` as a transport method for `rsync`. Of course, this is possible with Git as well. If used properly, I would consider both tools to be equally secure.

Comment: `rsync` isn't a backup utility either.  It's a file-copy utility.  `rdiff-backup` is a backup utility based on `rsync`.

Comment: You're making the assumption that he wants to diff things.

Comment: No, I'm not.  He commented that he wants “delta-based repositories”, and that was already clear from his desire to use Git or SVN.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I **do** need to run diff but I'm not sure a simple tool would suffice my needs. What advantages does `rsync` offer over `SVN` and `Git`?

Comment: Git makes an excellent backup utility.  I use it for that regularly.  I don't have a need for diffs, but I do have a need to go back to particular points in time.  I don't understand the mentality that seems to avoid using Unix tools other than how they're intended.  Unix tools are generally designed to be used in unintended ways.

Comment: Having said that, SVN would work, too, it's just slow as an old dog.

Comment: @DonBranson Well, I'm looking for the fastest dog out there ;)

Comment: The only drawback I've hit with git is its file-size limitation.  Any tracked file has to fit in memory.

Comment: @DonBranson File size is not a problem for me since not file would be more than a MB or so.

Comment: Next time, provide the necessary details in your question body.

Comment: @maček This tool seems great. I have to check it out to see if this works for my needs.

Comment: @maček You're right, but my project is very complicated and also confidential. I have to post a question with enough information, you're right. But I didn't know there was such tool out there. I have to look at the tool which you kindly mentioned and see if it fits the project I'm working on. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Downvote because rsync doesn't keep the previous versions. If you `rsync sync` your destination will completely change, therefore if the source is corrupted/empty, you're gonna delete your destination.

Answer (score 2):

For comparison see [GitSvnComparison](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison). Also, you can use Mercurial.

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted. Just one question: Is it possible to retrieve a single file of a particular revision from Git? I know SVN has this.

Comment: Just look on previous answer on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

> - Which one is more efficient for storage (takes less space)

The size of Subversion repository and Git repository with the same content [will be equal](http://svnvsgit.com/#repository-size-myth) unless the repo contains a huge number of binary items. In such case Git repository can take much more space than SVN repository.

> - Which one is more reliable (if there is a crash when pushing/committing, which one handles errors better)

My vote goes to SVN just because client-side operations with Git can break a repository or [repo history](http://svnvsgit.com/#git-history-is-not-safe). This could never happen with Subversion. Crash when pushing-committing should never cause any problems with both systems.

> Which one does things faster

Git is faster because the repository is always local. However, it will still take some time to clone the repo over network.

In Subversion you don't need to clone the whole repository; you just need to checkout the workspace and in most cases it takes less time than cloning Git repo.

> Which one can handle large-scale repositories better (if too many
>   revisions submitted, which would perform better)

Subversion is more suitable for large projects and repos than Git. See

- http://svnvsgit.com/#git-scalability-for-larger-project-myth
- http://svnvsgit.com/#git-scalability-for-larger-teams-myth

Comment: SVN Repositories are larger than git repositories in general. I converted a couple of them, was true in every single case, often by a factor of 10 and more. 
The svnvsgit page you link to claims stuff that is in most cases either wrong or misleading. SVN is superior in some cases, but those claims are far too simple and misleading.

Comment: @argeman would you mind showing some examples of the svn vs git repo size and your migration procedure?

Comment: I can't show you my examples as it is all not open source.
However, this comparison itself is completely useless; the svn repo is stored once (+backups), the git repository is stored at least once per machine where it is used (+backups). So, for a repository that doesn't fit to the target machine, git would just not work at all. If this is relevant depends on the exact use case.

Comment: Well, if you consider git-lfs also, the above mentioned issue just goes away. But that's a different story and it still doesn't make sense to compare repository sizes at all.